# bootstrap center image landscape iphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using boostrap 3 and at front page i have one image. Its fine center but when using iphone or tablet in landscape the image is too big. can you tell me how to make it responsive for landscape as well

http://garveydoyle.ie/sitenew/

Comment: Since your question is about the Twitter Bootstrap framework, you might want to add the [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `max-height:100vh` to your image's CSS. Hard to know for sure without seeing your code, but should work...

Comment: I hadn't either until a few weeks ago. Caveat, it doesn't work on <IE8 (does anything?). Also, please accept answer if it's working for you!

Answer (score 1):

The img-responsive class applies a max-width of 100%.  Therefore, in landscape mode on smaller devices where the container fills the viewport, the image will be cut off on the top and bottom if it is the width of the device.  Additionally, you have 55px of top margin set on your body, which further reduces the viewable height on a device in landscape orientation.

Using a media query to target devices in landscape mode to remove the body margin and change the img-responsive class to adjust the image for max-height instead of max-width should solve the problem.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1000px) and (orientation:landscape){
  body {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .img-responsive {
    max-width: initial;
    max-height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

If you really wanted to simplify your landing page down to its essence and have it center the image vertically and horizontally for all viewports, you could remove all of the extraneous divs and just do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://garveydoyle.ie/sitenew/about-us/">
        <img class="loading" src="http://garveydoyle.ie/sitenew/wp-content/themes/roots/assets/img/loading.jpg" alt="garvey doyle" />
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```